# Interrogation about the security of a LUKS disk encryption install

Tags: luks

I installed my system recently and opted to encrypt the `/home` partition using LUKS. This was done through an install script (arch-install).

The thing that led me to questioning the security of my setup is that the system didn't prompt me for my passphrase upon reboot. The disk is correctly encrypted and I can't access it without the passphrase on a live USB. I eventually figured that the reason I could access it without providing my passphrase is because it got configured to also use a keyfile that is stored in `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/homeloop.key`.

Here is my question: is that secure? To me it really looks like leaving the key to a locked door on the outside (my root partition isn't encrypted), but I also know nothing about disk encryption so I feel like I must be missing something, since that was generated by a script. I looked a bit through man cryptsetup and man cryptsetup-lucksAddKey, but this is a lot for a disk encryption neophyte as myself and I could not really find any reason why that would be a secure setup, so I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You can try to open your encrypted home from a live USB using the key you found. Something like `cryptsetup open --type luks --key-file /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/homeloop.key /encrypted/home/device name` (name is kinda arbitrary here). I don't know how Arch does it but it could be that the key is encrypted and decrypted with your login password when you login. But your concern is valid. (since this topic is new for you: if successfully opened you find a device /dev/mapper/name (name you chose before) and could mount it if you want to try go the full length)

Comment: @PaulPazderski thanks for you comment. It does actually work and de-encrypt the partition ! I'm a bit surprised the installation would make such a decision by default without informing the user -- or maybe i just didn't read, that's possible as well. Anyway I'll be looking into removing that key without breaking everything then. Have a good day!

Comment: If you don't have to enter any passphrase and the system loads encryption keys by itself without user interaction, then the key is under the doormat... if you have keys in /etc/... for additional partitions, it is assumed that the rootfs is already encrypted (it's normal to have car keys in your house but the house itself is locked). If you have any doubts about this key (if it was copied or leaked or stored unencrypted anywhere) you should make a new key and remove the old one, using luksChangeKey or similar. So that even if someone finds the old key, it won't work anymore.

Comment: @frostschutz Ah, thanks! I was wondering what would be the use of having the key under the root partition if it was encrypted, but I didn't consider that each partition would have a different key in which case it does make a lot of sense.